# User Reactions Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Does anyone know if it's possible to access user reactions on the Facebook Graph API? I'm able to access USER likes and POST reactions but not USER reactions. If I can access user likes it seems like it would be possible to access user reactions as well.

**This is all I can find:**

```
me?fields=id,name,likes

me?fields=id,name,posts{reactions}
```